# MySql query in same column for same date and same customer

Tags: invoice

Please I need your help. I am talking about MySQL Database.

This is my query :

SELECT llx_facturedet.rowid, llx_societe.nom, llx_societe_extrafields.prof, llx_facture.ref, llx_facture.date_valid, llx_product.label, llx_facturedet.qty, llx_facturedet.subprice, llx_facturedet.total_ht FROM llx_societe CROSS JOIN llx_societe_extrafields ON llx_societe.rowid = llx_societe_extrafields.fk_object CROSS JOIN llx_facture ON llx_societe.rowid = llx_facture.fk_soc CROSS JOIN llx_facturedet ON llx_facture.rowid = llx_facturedet.fk_facture CROSS JOIN llx_product ON llx_product.rowid = llx_facturedet.fk_product ORDER BY rowid;

Here is the result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV17X.png)

You can notice that, patient6 and patient8 took the same date the items Product1 and Service1.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFyVd.png)

Hence, their invoice references and names are included in each item added.

How can I solve this without ignoring any ordered items?

Comment: What was the result you were expecting?

Comment: I want to have a result so that in the fields name, prof, ref and date_valid the same values cannot be repeated when a customer has several items. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think this answer will do you (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099747/how-to-avoid-duplicate-on-joining-two-tables)